# FancyBox 3.5.7 - Can't Get Any Options to Work

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I have just downloaded Fancybox v3.5.7.
I am unable to get it to accept any options.
I get the icons, but no options I selct work.
Some examples... I can't get transitionEffect to work, nor fullScreen, nor animationEffect, nor right-click protection.

I have used the jquery and css on the cdn.jsdeliver.net site, so I know there can't be a problem with any of that. I have tried placing it in the head section and body section, without sucess.

I have tested on a few browsers, both from just computer, and also uploaded to the server.

I also tried just the basic starting code as provided indocumentation without any options...

```
<script>
$('[data-fancybox="Test-1"]').fancybox({
// Options will go here
});
</script>
```

I created a basic html page (with utf8), with no other jquery, so there is nothing that may conflict with fancybox...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="SKYPE_TOOLBAR" content="SKYPE_TOOLBAR_PARSER_COMPATIBLE" />
<meta name="MSSmartTagsPreventParsing" content="true">
<meta name="robots" content="noodp">
<meta name="robots" content="NOindex,NOfollow">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/fancyapps/fancybox@3.5.7/dist/jquery.fancybox.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/fancyapps/fancybox@3.5.7/dist/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

And on the body of the page is the test gallery, sample code is...

```
  <a data-fancybox="Test-1" href="https://source.unsplash.com/juHayWuaaoQ/"
  data-caption="Backpackers following a dirt trail">
  <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/juHayWuaaoQ/240x160" />
  </a>
```

So I wonder that the call and options are not coded correctly.
I have tried it in both the head section and the body section without success.
And I have tried various ways of editing the script code (I made comments there for reference)...

```
<script>
$('[data-fancybox="Test-1"]').fancybox({

// Options will go here
  thumbs : { autoStart:true },
  toolbar: "auto",
  arrows: true,
  infobar: true,
  smallBtn: "auto",
  preventCaptionOverlap: true,// DOESN'T WORK!!!
  arrows: true,
  infobar: true,
  smallBtn: "auto",
  protect: true,
  animationEffect: "zoom-in-out",// DOESN'T WORK!!!        // other options: "zoom"  "fade"  "zoom-in-out"  
  zoomOpacity: "auto",
  transitionEffect: "rotate", //DOESN'T WORK!!!            // other options: false "fade' "slide' "circular' "tube' "zoom-in-out' "rotate'
  spinnerTpl: '<div class="fancybox-loading"></div>',
  fullScreen: { autoStart:true }, //// DOESN'T WORK!!!     // I think this is for the large image to fill whole screen. doesn't work
});

//STAND-ALONE VAR DEFAULTS VERSION (apart from the call code) -DOESN'T WORK EITHER!!!
//tried in both head section and body
var defaults = {
  transitionEffect: "rotate",
  closeExisting: false,
  toolbar: "auto",
  arrows: true,
  infobar: true,
  smallBtn: "auto",
    protect: true
};

// THIS DOESN'T WORK EITHER. WITH OR WITHOUT MY SPECIAL Test-1 !!!
$('[data-fancybox="Test-1"]').fancybox({ 
    protect: true
});
</script>
```

Basically, I want certain options per gallery, so using the script tags and adding the various options of my choice is important and that is the part that seems to fail me.

Can anyone check out the codes provided above to see where I may have gone wrong?

If I can get this going, then other options I want to add will be easy for me.

Gallery name is Test 1 and it is referenced in both the script below and in the href tag in the body:  data-fancybox="Test-1"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you put your JS code after your HTML? Is `$('[data-fancybox="Test-1"]')` returning your elements?

Comment: Ah. That did the trick.  I had it before the html.

Comment: And yes, it all displayed correctly, just the options didn't work.
But your suggestion has made the options work. 
Thank you.